# Which commands are needed to set at top of the .vimrc file?

Tags: vim, set, command

My question is pretty clear in title, isn't it?
Actually I'm writing my .vimrc and I want to know which commands should be set at the top of a .vimrc file? (like `:set nocp` that it needs be be first in a .vimrc file (according to its help file))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I have `set nocompatible`, then [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) stuff (according to its docs), then just `set`s in alphabetic order and other commands. (By the way, 1928 lines that accumulated in my `.vimrc` over years work pretty well even after resourcing without any particular effort for that. I use indentation for sections, subsections, etc. to keep the config manageable.)

There are no mandatory commands, since if something must always be done for everyone, then this is not a part of a config.

In general, just write what you need step-by-step and fix any incompatibilities when they show up.

Answer (score 0):

No, `set nocompatible` is not necessary anywhere in your `vimrc`.

I've collected a number of battle-tested best practices in [this repository](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc).

Comment: @Cy8099, it's not a vimrc.